# unable to connect to openfire using strophe in phonegap app

Tags: cordova, xmpp, openfire, strophe

I am creating a phonegap application which tries to connect to xmpp server (openfire in my case) using strophe...but I always get Status.CONNFAIL as status in my call back function. what could be the reason. My simple code of index.html is as below :

```
$("#loginButton").click(function() {
    var username = $('input[name=username]').val();
    var password = $('input[name=password]').val();
    var conn = new Strophe.Connection(Powerchat.openfireConnectionURL);

    conn.connect(username, password, function(status) {
        alert(status);
        if (status === Strophe.Status.CONNECTED) {
            alert(status);
            $(document).trigger('connected');
        } else if (status === Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTED) {
            alert('disconnected 1');
            $(document).trigger('disconnected');
        }
    });
    Powerchat.connection = conn;
});
```

in the alert i always get 2 which comes in case of Status.CONNFAIL. I have listed openfireConnectionURL in my res/xml/cordova.xml

Comment: Are you testing this on a device? Provide some more details.

Comment: You can connect to the server successfully? or Is the Strophe.Connection() method getting executed successfully?